# Get GPS Coordinates on mouse tap/click on ArcGIS Esri Map in Windows Runtime Apps (Windows 8.1)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, windows, arcgis-online-basemaps, windows-10, windows-8.1

How to get the GPS coordinates (longitude, latitude) of the clicked/tapped point in ArcGIS Esri map?

I tried `MapViewTapped` event like:

```
private void myMapView_MapViewTapped(object sender, MapViewInputEventAtgs e)
{
  var x = e.Position.X; //e.Location.X;
  var y = e.Position.Y; //e.Location.Y;
}
```

Both gives large unexpected values.

Answer (score 1):

In a web map you would be getting back web Mercator coordinates (Meters) not geographic Lat/Longs.

In ArcGIS Desktop you would be getting back the projection of the data frame. I would change the map projection to 4326 (WGS-84) and then try it, it should the return Lat/Long decimal degrees. If this works then your issue is solved by using some coordinate conversion in your code.

Comment: Hi @Bill Chappell, I'm bit confused. Any idea how to change those map projection to 4326 (WGS-84)

Comment: If your in Web Mercator going to WGS-84 this might help.http://www.gal-systems.com/2011/07/convert-coordinates-between-web.html  if your in desktop and the data has coordinate information(Projection) then you can set the data frame to 4326 and the data should re-project on the fly.